# Implement clientside token-based authentication using plain Javascript/AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, token, http-status-code-401

Can anyone point me to an article that explains clientside token auth implementation using Javascript?

I found many articles on Angular but that is not what I'm looking for. That brings me to the question if it is possible to be done with Javascript.

Also how to handle scenarios when the auth server throws a 401. Is there a built in exception to detect that response? Or is a custom exception required to be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me..

```
var token = gettoken();
function getDatatypes() {
    if (isEmpty(token)) {
        token = gettoken();

    }

    var request = getDatatypesFromApi();
        request.success(function (data) {
            alert('success!');

        });
        request.error(function (httpObj, textStatus) {
            if (httpObj.status == 401)
                gettoken();
        });    
}
function getDatatypesFromApi() {
    var request = $.ajax
 ({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://yoururl.com/",
     data: '',
     headers:{
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token
     },
     dataType: "json",
     timeout: 5000,
 });
    return request;
}
function gettoken() {
    var credentials = {
        username: "userid",
        password: "PASS",
        domain: "",
        extensionsAppId:"{extAppId}"

    };
    var url = "http://thelinktoresource/"
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: { userId: credentials.username, password: credentials.password, domain: credentials.domain, extensionsAppId: credentials.extensionsAppId },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (Data) {
            console.log(Data);
            token = Data.replace(/"/ig, ''); 
            return token;
        },

        error: function () {
            alert('Error occured');
            return "undefined";
        }
    });

}

function isEmpty(strIn) {
    if (strIn === undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (strIn == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (strIn == "") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used JSON web tokens in one of my projects.
**http://blog.slatepeak.com/creating-a-simple-node-express-api-authentication-system-with-passport-and-jwt** is a tutorial on how to set up JSON web tokens on the server side.

Once you get the token as a response to the client side, you can store the token on window.localStorage.

```
var credentials = {
    username : document.getElementById("username").value,
    password : document.getElementById("password").value
};
var url = window.localStorage.getItem('appUrl');
$.ajax({
  url: url + '/register',
  type: 'POST', 
  data: { username: credentials.username, password: credentials.password },
  success: function(Data) {
           window.localStorage.setItem('token', Data.token);
          },
  beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', window.localStorage.getItem('token'));},
  error: function() {
          alert('Error occured');
          }
});
```

});

Then you can attach it in an AJAX call as a header while navigating to other pages.

```
$.ajax
 ({
  type: "GET",
  url: "index1.php",
  data: '{}',
  beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',window.localStorage.getItem('token')); 
  },
 success: function (){
  alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
 }
});
```